# Time invariance of a summation sequence

Tags: linear-systems

The following sequence is given which is supposed to be time-variant:

$$y[n] = \sum_{k=n_0}^n x[k]$$

I'm having difficulties proving the time-variance or finding a counterexample for it being time-invariant.
My idea (which proves it being time-invariant?) is:

\begin{align}y_1[n] &= T\{x_1[n]\}\\x_2[n] &= x_1[n-n_0]\end{align}

check, whether    $T\{x_1[n]\} = y_1[n-n_0]$

$$y_2[k] = \sum_{k=n_0}^n x_2[k] = \sum_{k=n_0}^n x_1[k - n_0] = \sum_{k=n_0-n_0}^{n-n_0} x_1[k] = y_1[n-n_0]$$

Where is my mistake? Working around the summation is giving me trouble.

**EDIT:**
Following the advice in the comments for $n = n_0$ the left equation equals to 1 while the right equation equals to 0, making both equations unequal and therefore the sequence time-variant?

**Second sequence**

This sequence is supposed to be time-invariant.

\begin{align}y[n] &= \sum_{k=n-n_0}^{n+n_0} x[k]\\
y_2[k] &= \sum_{k=n-n_0}^{n+n_0} x_2[k] = \sum_{k=n-n_0}^{n+n_0} x_1[k - n_0] = \sum_{k=n_0-2n_0}^{n} x_1[k] = y_1[n-n_0]\end{align}

I followed the same steps but I'm still not sure about for the case $n = n_0$ since when added in left and right equation

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}$$

They seem unequal to me?

Comment: What is the relationship connecting arrays $$ x_2[.] $$ and $$ x_1[.] $$ of your expressions?

Comment: Added to original post. $x_2$ is a shifted $x_1$

Comment: Does the last equation hold if n < n_0? (summation from zero to negative index)

Comment: I also thought about that, then the summation equals to 0. However if $n < n_0$ then the left summation also equals to 0 and both the equations are equal? I could possibly find a pair of $n$ and $n_0$ for which the equations are not equal.

Comment: Let n = n_0. Then y[n_0] = x[n_0]. The x series left-shifted by n_0 indices is x[n - n_0]; and the summation is y_shifted[n_0] = x[0]. Right?

Comment: In other words, for $n = n_0$ the left sum is equal to 1 and the right sum is equal to 0 making both equations unequal?

Comment: Don't know; it's just a hint. You have to decide for yourself.

Comment: if $n_0=-\infty$ it's Time-Invariant.  otherwise it's not.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You are correct but please say so one more time. Remember what the Captain said in Lewis Carroll's _The Hunting of the Snark_ "What I tell you three times is true!"

Comment: i dunno why the comment was duped.  only now noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sequences* that are "time-invariant" must be constants (not varying with time at all).

What the OP is actually asking about is a (discrete-time) *system* whose response $y$ to the input $x$ is defined to be
$$y[n] = \begin{cases}\sum_{k=n_0}^n x[k], & n \geq n_0,\\??? & n < n_0\end{cases}$$
where the $???$ is there because according to some traditionalists, if $n < n_0$, then that sum is an *empty sum* which has value $0$ but more liberal-minded might treat that sum as representing $$x[n] + x[n+1] + x[n+2] + \cdots + x[n_0-1] + x[n_0]$$ (with more serious-minded folks even *negating* that sum in analogy with the standard result that for $a<b$, $\int_b^a = -\int_a^b$). So, for the traditional meaning of things and $n_0$ denoting a (finite) integer, the *system* is *not* a time-invariant system. It *is* time-invariant (with unit pulse response $h[n]$ being the unit step function $u[n]$) if $n_0 = -\infty$ as noted in a comment by Robert Bristow-Johnson on the main question.

Comment: Would you please explain how the system becomes time-invariant when $n_0 = -\infty$? The left equation is $\sum_{k=\infty}^n x_2[k]$ and the right equation $\sum_{k=0}^{n-(-\infty)} x_1[k] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x_1[k]$ ?

Comment: $- \infty$ on the left equation*

Comment: If $n_0=-\infty$, then \begin{align}y[n]&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^nx[k]\\&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^nu[n-k]x[k]\\&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty u[n-k]x[k]\\&=u\star x\big\vert_n\end{align} where we have used the fact that $u[n-k]=1$ whenever $k$ is such that $n-k\geq 0$, i.e. $k \leq n$ and $u[n-k]=0$ whenever $k$ is such that $n-k<0$, i.e. $k>n$. So, we have expressed the output as a convolution of $x$ with a fixed impulse response (the unit step function) and so we have a time-invariant system, in fact, a _linear_ time-invariant system.

Comment: Thank you very much!